# Drag and drop into a panel in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

I wanna make a div draggable into another div like this example:
http://examples.extjs.eu/freedrag.html
Is there a way to do it in Extjs 4

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question.
http://examples.extjs.eu/freedrag.js